# Detect Windows shutdown with C# 

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I want to stop my C# application from running after the user has clicked shut down of computer so any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 8):

you can use [CloseReason.WindowsShutDown](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/searchform.aspx?search=CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) for this purpose inside the form closing event.

```
if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
else
{
    e.Cancel = false;
}
```